# How can I insert array in the middle of another array in es6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays:

```
let a = [1, 3, 5];
let b = [2, 4];
```

I need to put second array into first one after second element, so this is result:

```
[1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
```

What is the best way to insert second array into first in es6?

It can be easily solved using concat operation, but I am looking for nice way of doing it in es6.

Comment: I need to put second array at specific position, not in the end.

Comment: @ruslan5t, please refer to [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's easier to help if you give us all required criteria at the beginning, instead of editing the question and changing your issue later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to insert the second array at specific index, you can use `splice` function and **spread operator**.

```
var a = [1, 3, 5];
var b = [2, 4, 6];

a.splice(2, 0, ...b);

console.log(a); // [1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5]
```

Comment: I need to put second array in the middle of first one, not in the end.

Comment: @ruslan5t, I updated my answer to better fit your question.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37152508/218196). You could use the term *spread argument*.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```
a.splice(2, 0, ...b)
```

```js
let a = [1, 2, 5];
let b = [3, 4];

a.splice(2, 0, ...b);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: I don't want to sort arrays, I need to put second one in first one at specific position.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37152508/218196). You could use the term *spread argument*.

Comment: @FelixKling : sorry , I just updated :) ... thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer you're looking for:

```
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
    let arr3 = [...arr2];
    arr3.splice(n, 0, ...arr1);
    return arr3;
}
```